How can github ssh url be coded as c# uri?
Im trying to represent a github ssh url as c# uir. The url has the format
git@github.com:user/project.git

When trying to create the uri class like this
Uri siteUri = new Uri("ssh://git@github.com:user/project.git");

an exception is thrown
System.UriFormatException: "Invalid URI: Invalid port specified."

But according to the source of the uri class it seems to be possible to use collon :  without port.
Has someone an idea how?
I searched the net without success.

Use the ssh scheme

Unfortunatly no change in behavior with ssh scheme. (now url in above post with scheme).

var uri = new UriBuilder("ssh:git@github.com:user/project.git");

This results also in the same exception:  Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.

It seems SSH doesn't follow the official RFC3986 which defines URI formats, which allow a user before the @ but after the : should be a port number. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75673 So the Uri class is the wrong type to use for such a piece of text as it's not a valid URI.

That's for you to check the content of the UriBuilder; you see that ssh: is the schema, and the rest is the path.  See Git URIs does not match SSH URI specification
